# nginx won't restart due to error regarding map_hash_bucket_size

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get my site moved over to a later version of nginx (from **1.11.13** to **1.17.5**)

In my **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**, I have:

```
http {

 ... other stuff

    map_hash_max_size 262144;
    map_hash_bucket_size 262144;
    map $uri $is_rewrite {
        default     no_redirect;
        include /home/fatpeter/conf/web/chambres.com.extra/links.map;
    }

   ..more stuff

}
```

Thie links.map file is 14mb (I know its big, but we have a lot of old URL formats that we having to 301)

When I restart nginx I get:

```
service nginx restart
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The error comes up as:

```
Nov 14 11:25:56 admin2.site.com systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Nov 14 11:25:56 admin2.site.com nginx[21418]: nginx: [emerg] could not build map_hash, too large map_hash_bucket_size: 262144
Nov 14 11:25:56 admin2.site.com systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

Has something changed around that? The documents seem to suggest its still a valid setting

Comment: You don't need map_hash_bucket_size that big. Use some sane value like `128`. https://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks for the reply. What does the 128k stand for? To me it seems like the overall .map file size (which is 15mb)... or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @AlexeyTen as expected - putting it to 128 gives me: `nginx: [emerg] could not build map_hash, you should increase map_hash_bucket_size: 128
`

Comment: Try to increase it. But not to 260k

Comment: @AlexeyTen ah cool - setting to 200 worked :) Please add that as an answer, and I will accept when it allows me :) Not sure why the large number worked on the old version of nginx - maybe the values mean't something different?